# My question is about bootstrap responsive grid system

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, django

Suppose i have two columns in a row each of them are col-6 in left side i have text and the right side i have an image i gave the text-end class to the 2nd column i want to change the class from text-end to text-center in the md , sm screen how to do that ? can anyone guide me ? i just want to use the bootstrap not the custom class of css and make it to the center through media query ?

i have used media query to do my task but i just want the bootstrap class to do it without any type of custom css i am expecting that i will get my answer from this platform ..
thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<p class="text-center text-sm-right">Some text here</p>
```

because bootstrap is made for mobile first design, your inital text-align class will be text-center... after the sm breakpoint that is: 576px, you change the text align to end.

In short text-sm-right means:
If the screen is bigger than 576px, align text to the right...